# if admin is logged in

Tags: admin

We know, that `is_admin()` checks if current URL belongs to DASHBOARD (**BUT it doenst check whether user is ADMIN**).

So, I use this function to detect if administrator is logged in wordpress:

```
function is_admin_user(){
  require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-includes/pluggable.php'); return current_user_can('create_users'); //or 'manage_options'
}
```

however, that is not ideal solution. Does there exist any built-in function, like `wp_is_administrator()`?

Comment: `if(current_user_can('administrator'))`

Comment: What your code suggests is that you use some kinda bootstrap to laod WP functions outside WP but even in this case you can use what Howdy_McGee says -> [see documenation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Answer (score 25):

[`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) will accept a role name but, sadly, the behavior with roles [is not entirely consistent](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624).

The following should work and is simpler than what you have, by a little bit.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' )) {
  // user is an admin
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the simplest way would in fact be to use [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) as such:

```
if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ){} // only if administrator
```

This seems like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404284/wordpress-capabilities-and-current-user-can-in-functions-php).